# Where can I check the happiness

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

Where can I check the [happiness](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Happiness) from my Pokemon on Pokemon White ? I Know that there is a NPC who can say it to you using some [phrase](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Happiness#Happiness_raters). But there is other way to check it or is it the **ONLY** way to see they happiness ?

I am asking this because I have a lot of Pokemons that need evolution (by happiness) and I want to know how much everyone has before I start leveling them.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two characters listed there are the only ways to check happiness levels in B/W as far as I know. There is no way to find out the exact value in-game.

However, there is an online tool called [PokeCheck](http://www.pokecheck.org/) that can give you all the exact stats of your Pokemon, including happiness. (It works by "intercepting" a connection to the GTS and recording the Pokemon data; nothing is traded away or modified.)

If you need to evolve Pokemon by happiness the easiest solution is to make them old the Soothe Bell and keep them in your party while you train others. You can let them battle a bit, but don't let them faint. Some other methods like massages are listed on Bulbapedia.